# What are trade markouts?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency, algorithmic-trading

I have experience in trading but mostly in lower frequency quantitative trading. I've moved into HFT research and someone the other day mentioned markouts. I couldn't find anything online explaining what markouts are.

Comment: A 
Google search returned this as one of the top results https://iextrading.com/docs/A%20Comparison%20of%20Execution%20Quality%20across%20U.S.%20Stock%20Exchanges.pdf Seems like "markout" is used to refer to the virtual profit and loss of closing out a position after a fixed time using a specific rule (e.g. mid / other side / ...). See Section 5.1 in the paper for details.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard it more commonly called a "markup", but either way, it's the difference between a current price (e.g. a trade price) and some microprice (midpt, or some fancier fair-value estimate) at some time in the future, typically some number of seconds, or quote updates.  Sometimes people refer to just this future micro-price as the markup.   It's used at the target value for fitting high-frequency models.