Are you familiar with the expression DPM (dollar per millions)?
I was talking with a forex trader about the markout chart.
He proceed to firstly tell me about another metric called the dpm (doller per millions).
I understand that it's a way to measure the different instrument pair on the same base so that you can chose the current most performant for your position.
The thing is that, I don't find any information of this on google.
It seems to be very common in the trading analysis field so I assume it's just called differently.
Do you see what I'm talking about ?

I've never heard of "dollar per million". But "defects per million (DPM)" are often used in quality control writings, particularly in "Six Sigma (6σ)" methodology. e.g.  https://www.6sigma.us/process-improvement/six-sigma-defects-per-million/ Maybe this refers to operational risk in FX trading operations?

Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41559

Just guessing, could it simply be the market impact of buying/selling 1 million of a currency in terms of how it affects the currency's USD value? Another term I have seen could be for example USD per million EUR traded.

I can't really talk about it more than what I did, sadly it's not my field. In the application I'm developping we have many currency pair and we "transform" them to dollar per millions in order to see how much pip impact a currency for a currency pair.
